# Add object to array failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I am building an array that will host objects with a student's name, their grade and z score (currently value is set to null) but am having trouble loading the objects.

The object is meant to look like this:

```
var 000 = {
    name: "John Doe",
    grade: 92,
    zScore: null
};
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/kogx7Lks/2/)

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder= "Name . . .">
    <input type="text" id="grade" placeholder = "Grade . . . ">
    <button id="add">Add</button>
    <button id="doMath">Do Math</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <ul id="list"></ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#name:hover,#grade:hover {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var studentArray = [];
var oid = 001;
var studentName = $('#name').val();
var studentGrade = (parseInt($('#name').val()));
var zScore = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add').on('click', function() {
        if (studentName === "" || studentGrade === "") {
            return;
        };
        oid = {
            name: studentName,
            grade: studentGrade,
            z: zScore
        };
        //check it out
        console.log(oid);
        //push object to array
        studentArray.push(oid);
        //check out array
        console.log(studentArray);
        //push OID up for next student and reset inputs
        $('#name').val("");
        $('#grade').val("");
        oid++;
    });
    $('#doMath').on('click', function() {});
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: var 000? does that work?

Comment: That's a sample. `var oid` actually starts at `001`

Comment: uh, oid starts as a number, then you assign an object to it, then you try to increment that object...won't work!

Comment: you're setting the value of student grade with #name and not #grade. Also you'll need to grab those values within your click function otherwise they will always be empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by adding to an array you're essentially disregarding the object name. Perhaps instead you could use a parent object?

```
var studentObj = {};
var oid = 001;
var studentName = "evan";
var studentGrade = "a";
var zScore = null; 
//push to object
studentObj[oid] = {
    name: studentName,
    grade: studentGrade,
    z: zScore
};
//check out object
console.log(studentObj);
//push OID up for next student and reset inputs
$('#name').val("");
$('#grade').val("");
oid++;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kogx7Lks/3/

Comment: In the code there is `studentArray[oid] = {
        name: studentName,
        grade: studentGrade,
        z: zScore` but when I open up the console, grade comes before student. Why is this?

Comment: whats the end goal? how are you planning on displaying the data?

Comment: Isn't displaying it alphabetically confusing? I am planning on accessing the score property to eventually calculate the z score property. The end goal is to display z scores. I have not yet decided how to display the data yet but probably a list for now with the name, grade and z score.

Comment: I added a quick function for #doMath click at the bottom, take a look https://jsfiddle.net/kogx7Lks/6/

Comment: I actually have not seen the `hasOwnProperty` method yet so I looked it up. Am I correct in understanding that what it is doing is accessing the properties by name? E.g. `studentArray[property].grade` gets the grade but couldn't you use `studentArray.grade` ?

Comment: no because studentArray houses ALL records. Grade belongs to an individual record. You must first specify which record you want the grade for. So you could in theory say `studentArray.001.grade`, `studentArray.002.grade`, etc

Comment: I thought that would be accessed using `each` then diving into the values, ok.

Answer (score 1):

see this code it help you you assign value every time when click:

```
$('#add').on('click', function() {
    studentName = $('#name').val();
    studentGrade = (parseInt($('#name').val()));
    ...
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kogx7Lks/4/